# Mongodo db delete documents between custom fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I have below documents in mongodb, am trying to delete the documents based on the `referenceId` field between the values `X0000000005` and `X00000000010`, I couldnt find any articles for deleting mongo documents based on custom field, can someone please help me to do this deletion if its possible?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0f13ad0a83924b84d16b7d"),    
    "senderId" : "783",
    "clientId" : "146196",
    "referenceId" : "X00000000001",    
    "file" : "jAAAAAECAAABaAAAAKQAAJyMKYqPYvFQKJrZ/fqYjDKNdXdOMK58tPQ"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0f13ad0a83924b84d16b7e"),    
    "senderId" : "783",
    "clientId" : "146196",
    "referenceId" : "X00000000002",    
    "file" : "jAAAAAECAAABaAAAAKQAAJyMKYqPYvFQKJrZ/fqYjDKNdXdOMK58tPQ"
}
.
.
.
.
.
.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0f13ad0a83924b84d16b7f"),    
    "senderId" : "783",
    "clientId" : "146196",
    "referenceId" : "X00000000020",    
    "file" : "jAAAAAECAAABaAAAAKQAAJyMKYqPYvFQKJrZ/fqYjDKNdXdOMK58tPQ"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following simple query should work:

```
db.collection.remove({"referenceId":{$gte:"X00000000005"}, "referenceId":{$lte:"X00000000010"}})
```

You might want to run a `find()` using the same filter first in order to make sure that the `delete()` will affect the right records. That'd obviously be this then:

```
db.collection.find({"referenceId":{$gte:"X00000000005"}, "referenceId":{$lte:"X00000000010"}})
```

Also, depending on the exact definition of your

> between the values `X0000000005` and `X00000000010`

you might need to swap the `$lte` and `$gte` operators out for something else (`$gt` and/or `$lt`).

Answer (score 1):

db.collection.remove({"referenceId": {"$lte": "X00000000010", "gte": "X0000000005"}})